# Typescript error in React Redux connect function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am trying to write a React Redux component using Typescript following the documentation in [Redux Getting Started](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) and [Proper Typing of react-redux Connected Components](https://medium.com/knerd/typescript-tips-series-proper-typing-of-react-redux-connected-components-eda058b6727d) and am getting a type error on my `connect` function.

My app uses Redux to maintain a table of questions.

**state.tsx**

```
import {AnyAction, combineReducers} from "redux";

const ADD_QUESTION = "ADD_QUESTION";

export interface Question {
    id: number,
    text: string
}

export interface State {
    questions: QuestionsTable
}

interface QuestionsTable {
    nextId: number,
    questions: Question[]
}

const questions = (state: State = {questions: {nextId: 0, questions: []}}, action: AnyAction): State => {
    const questions = state.questions;
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_QUESTION:
        return {
            ...state,
            questions: {
                ...questions,
                nextId: questions.nextId + 1,
                questions: questions.questions.concat([{id: questions.nextId, text: action.text}])
            }
        };
        default:
            return questions
    }
};

export const reducers = combineReducers({
    questions
});
```

A `Questions` component displays them. I use `connect` to create `QuestionsContainer` from that.

**questions.tsx**

```
import React from "react"
import {Question, State} from "../state";
import {connect} from "react-redux";

export type QuestionsProps = {
    questions: Question[]
}

const Questions: React.FC<QuestionsProps> = ({questions}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {questions.map(question => (
                    <li>{question.text}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: QuestionsTable): QuestionsProps => {
    return {questions: state.questions.questions};
};

export const QuestionsContainer = connect<QuestionsProps>(mapStateToProps)(Questions);
```

My top-level app displays this container component.

**App.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import {reducers} from "./state";
import {createStore} from "redux"
import {Provider} from "react-redux"
import {QuestionsContainer} from "./components/questions";

const store = createStore(reducers);
const App: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <div className="App">
                <QuestionsContainer/>
            </div>
        </Provider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

I get a type error in my call to `connect`.

```
Error:(61, 59) TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(state: State) => QuestionsProps' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MapStateToPropsParam<QuestionsProps, {}, {}>'.
      Type '(state: State) => QuestionsProps' is not assignable to type 'MapStateToPropsFactory<QuestionsProps, {}, {}>'.
        Types of parameters 'state' and 'initialState' are incompatible.
          Property 'questions' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'State'.
```

If I suppress this error with `@ts-ignore` and log the value of `questions` passed to my `Questions` component I see this.

```
{"nextId":0,"questions":[]}
```

I can't figure out why the `nextId` field is there even though `mapStateToProps` dereferences `state.questions.questions`.

What is the correct way to set this up?

Comment: In a reducer you are returning {nextId: 0, questions: []} as a default value of questions.
According to your  mapStateToProps, you have to use return {questions: state.questions.questions};
Also, first parameter of reducer is a state

Comment: I was confused about the arguments that should be passed to a reducer. I edited the question to fix this. I'm still seeing pretty much the same error, though.

Comment: export const QuestionsContainer = connect<QuestionsProps, {}>(mapStateToProps)(Questions); can you try exporting it this way and see if you get the same error?

Answer (score 1):

Okay 
I will try it from phone
Sorry for formatting

```
import {AnyAction, combineReducers} from "redux";

const ADD_QUESTION = "ADD_QUESTION";

export interface Question {
    id: number,
    text: string
}

interface State {
    nextId: number,
    items: Question[]
}

const initialState: State = {nextId: 0,  items: []}

const questions = (state = initialState, action: AnyAction): State => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_QUESTION:
        return {
            ...state,
            items: action.items,
            nextId: action.nextId
        };
        default:
            return state
    }
};

export const reducers = combineReducers({
    questions
});
```

That's how I see your reducer

Then in component in mapStateToProps
questions: state.questions.items